# Terraform, Creating an optional list of maps

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create an optional iam policy but i keep getting errors of the type not matching, i've tried wrapping it in try's and such but it's never successful, anyone have any ideas?

```
  ssm_readonly_policies = can(coalescelist(local.ssm_parameters)) ? [
    {
      Sid    = "ReadOnlyParametersSSM"
      Effect = "Allow"
      Action = [
        "ssm:GetParameter*"
      ]
      Resource = flatten([for param in local.ssm_parameters : join(":", [
        "arn:aws:ssm", param["region"], param["account"], join("/", ["parameter", param["name"]])
      ])])
    },
    {
      Sid      = "ListOnlyParametersSSM"
      Effect   = "Allow"
      Action   = "ssm:DescribeParameters"
      Resource = "*"
    }
  ] : []
```

the format of local.ssm_parameters is

```
ssm_parameters = [
   {
     name = "blah"
     region = "blah"
     account = "blah"
   }
 ]
```

Comment: If `ssm_parameters` is a local with hardcoded values, then would it not always be non-empty by definition?

Comment: ssm_parameters is empty by default, it only has values if provided by the user, this is within a module

Comment: Can you edit your question to instead include something actually runnable please? It's hard to see exactly how you're calling this and ideally your question's code should take the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Also, a bit of a frame challenge but do you really need the ability to get parameters from another account and/or region? Normally parameters would be created in the same region and account as whatever is accessing them and unless you have a concrete use case for cross region and cross account access (including how you are handling IAM for cross account) you could drastically simplify this by only needing the parameter name/path.

Comment: Yes there are use-cases where occasionally ssm parameters from other accounts are required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok i got around it by avoiding an if statement by adding coaleselist within a try so if it's empty it will fail to an empty list

```
  ssm_readonly_policies = try([
    {
      Sid    = "ReadOnlyParametersSSM"
      Effect = "Allow"
      Action = [
        "ssm:GetParameter*"
      ]
      Resource = flatten([for param in coalescelist(local.ssm_parameters) : join(":", [
        "arn:aws:ssm", param["region"], param["account"], join("/", ["parameter", param["name"]])
      ])])
    },
    {
      Sid      = "ListOnlyParametersSSM"
      Effect   = "Allow"
      Action   = "ssm:DescribeParameters"
      Resource = "*"
    }
  ], [])
```